# What's an example of an event (or what types of events) that's a tail-sigma-algebra event, but that is not a shift-invariant-sigma-algebra event?

Tags: probability, measure-theory, stochastic-processes

According to my lecture notes, we define the tail sigma-algebra, $\mathscr{T}$ to be
$$\mathscr{T} := \bigcap_n \mathscr{T}_n$$
where
$$\mathscr{T}_n := \sigma (X_n, X_{n+1}, \cdots)$$

On the other hand, we define the shift-invariant sigma-algebra, $\mathcal{T}$ to be
$$\mathcal{T} := \\{A \subset \Omega: \phi^{-1}(A) = A\\}$$
where
$$\phi(X_0, X_1, \cdots) := (X_1, X_2, \cdots)$$

Also according to my lecture notes,
$$\mathcal{T} \subset \mathscr{T}$$
I can see why it's a subset, but not proper.  What is an example of event (or what "types" of events) that's in the tail sigma-algebra, but not the shift-invariant sigma-algebra?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose a sequence $(c_k)$ of distinct real numbers and consider
$$
A = \{\omega \mid \exists \, N , \forall k \geq N, X_k(\omega) = c_k\}.
$$
This is a tail event that is not invariant by the shift. Taking union of such events gives other such sets, which are not invariant by the shift in general.